# Preciso mostrar os dados do cliente que mais comprou

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: relacionamentos do banco:]

Essa consulta esta dando erro:

```
select c.* from carrinho_de_compras as cc
    inner join clientes as c
        on c.codigo = cc.cod_cliente
    inner join produtos as p
        on p.codigo = cc.cod_produto
    where (select count(produtos.codigo) from produtos)
 
não entendo bem essa lógica das sub-consultas. Alguém pode me explicar?
```

Comment: Que erro que essa consulta deu?

Comment: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type bigint
LINE 6:     where (select count(produtos.codigo) from produtos)

Comment: `where (select count(produtos.codigo) from produtos)` consegue nos explicar o que tentou fazer nessa linha?

Comment: listar a quantidade de produtos inseridos

Comment: Dentro do `where`?

Comment: sim, eu tentei fazer uma sub query ali. O plano era listar a quantidade de produtos de cada cliente e depois mostrar qual cliente comprou mais.

Comment: O `where` é para fazer expressões lógica, condições, não pode ser usado assim... teria de ser algo como `where campo < (select ....)`. Esse `select` deveria estar no `from`

Comment: entendi vou alterar aqui, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

resolvi assim:

```
                  select 
                        C.nome,              
                        count(CC) as total_compras
                    from 
                        carrinho_de_compras as CC, clientes as C
                    where
                        C.codigo = CC.cod_cliente                       
                    group by C.codigo
                    having count(CC) = 
                        (select MAX(
                            (                           
                            select                       
                                count(CC)
                            from 
                                carrinho_de_compras as CC
                            where
                                C.codigo = CC.cod_cliente                               
                            )) 
                        from clientes as C)
```

Dessa forma ele lista os nomes dos clientes que mais compraram produtos.

Espero que sirva de ajuda para alguém.